# QGIS - clip - R st_intersection - problem concerning clipping/intersection

Tags: r, intersection, qgis, clip

I have layer of 164000 buffers (buffer of 1km generated around a point) which is to be clipped by one or more of approx 1.2 millions polygons representing green areas. Most of the green areas do not intersect with buffer. I want to calculate the combined area of the green areas within the buffer. The buffer layer contains an attribute table with 164 000 rows.

How do I get a result attribute table from the buffer layer with an additional column of the area of the green areas within the buffer?

I have tried the clip function i QGIS, but it takes forever on my dataset and I had to abort. I tried halving the datasets in the layer, but still no results within many hours.

I tried doing this in R with the st_intersection function, but I got more than 164000 rows. I want only the rows in the buffer with one or additional columns representing the area.

And solution in QGIS or R would be greatly appreciated

Comment: well you can choose the correct rows if you fiddle with `st_intersects()` first. This is faster because it just returns (basically) a yes/no answer for any given row/geometry

Comment: I read somewhere that the st_intersects() does not return topology. Does that mean I cannot calculate the area of the green areas within the buffer?

Comment: Maybe I understand you now. I use the st_intersects() to select the polygons that intersects thereby greatly reducing the number of intersections and then I can do the st_intersection on the result?  I still need to union the green areas if several are within the buffer though

Comment: yes that was my thinking. some geometry calculations will be necessary.

my advice for those would be to transform your coordinates to a planar crs (like EPSG:4978) instead of one using degrees (like epsg 4326) because it takes `st_intersection()` forever to compute them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The crs was EPSG:25833 ETRS UTM zone 33N, so that should be ok